# How to use screen when /dev/tty is disabled?

Tags: gnu-screen, tty, firejail

Firejail provides secure environment that strips /dev files with little number of exception. So when I try to run `screen` inside the environment, I get "Must be connected to a terminal". `tty` responds with "not a tty".

Is it possible to get proper tty in user space and pass it to screen?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to create user mode tty with the typescript utility. It looks like an overdo, but it works. So, the simple but probably not optimal solution is:

```
script -c "screen -R script" /dev/null
```

And it would be helpful to export appropriate `TERM` environment variable.